# Update primary key value along with foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, primary-key

Suppose I have 3 database tables 
 **Project(Id,...)**, **Task(Project_Id,...)** , **Duration(Project_Id,...)**

**Id** is primary key in **Project** and **Id** is foreign key for **Task** and **Duration**

Is it possible to update the value of **Id** with immediate effect on the child tables?

N.B: Identity is enabled Primary Key

Comment: Use the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option in the foreign key constraint definition.

Comment: It sounds like you are using an identity? If so, no you can't update the value and why would you want to?